# Mac M1 Setting Java Version to Unity's AndroidPlayer SDK Version

Tags: java, command-line

How can I link my Java runtime on my M1 Mac to the Java JDK installed by Unity for my project. I am currently using version 2021.3.16f1, and the path to the Java executable is /Applications/Unity/Hub/Editor/2021.3.16f1/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer/OpenJDK/bin/java

Answer (score 0):

You can copy the link of the Java JDK from the Unity External Tools screen in options, and set JAVA_HOME to that path. For example: `alias java_8="export JAVA_HOME=\"/Applications/Unity/Hub/Editor/2021.3.16f1/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer/OpenJDK\"; java -version"`